# automatically execute a script after catkin_make doc

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

I wonder whether is possible to configure catkin somehow to automatically run a script (or CMake function) when `catkin_make doc` is called.

I have many different doxygen index.html files (one for each ROS package) and I am using CMake to store a log.txt with the location of the index.html. Then I would like to run a CMake `configure_file` command using the input from the log.txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Simple Solution

The probably simplest way is to write a small wrapper script, that first calls catkin and then your script. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
catkin_make doc
your_script.sh
```

Of course, this could be made more sophisticated by, for example, first checking if some errors occurred during `catkin_make`.

## CMake Solution

If the simple solution is not an option (for example, because we don't want to break the workflow of other users), it is also possible to add a "post build" command for a target in CMake with [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html) using the "POST_BUILD COMMAND" option:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET doc
    POST_BUILD COMMAND your_script.sh
)
```

(I am not sure if this will work as intended for target `doc`, maybe you have to experiment a bit.)

Comment: I have thought about that. However, that slightly modifies the workflow of the rest the people, and that is something undesirable. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @JaviV: All right, I see your point. After short googleing, I found [add_custom_command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html). I am not sure if this can solve your problem, but it looks promising (it provides the option to add a "post_build command").

Comment: please add that as answer so I can accept it since it does what I want.

Comment: @JaviV: Done. Is my code example working as intended with target `doc`? Feel free to edit my post if something has to be changed.